# Detect access to data from a method in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a method and I want to find all data accessed inside this method.

for example:

```
public class foo
{
    private int field;

    public void method()
    {
         field = 0;
    }
}
```

I need a way to know (from the source code or the assembly) that 'field' is accessed within 'method'.

**Note:** I already used Harmony Library (https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony) to find all the calls to methods inside a specific method. It would be amazing if someone knows how to use it to also find data accessed.

Comment: The Microsoft way of doing it is [Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/). Isn't Harmony an aspect oriented injection tool?

Comment: @OguzOzgul I can't precisely tell what Harmony is for now as I use it since yesterday only. I was thinking more about using reflection than Roslyn.

Comment: Ok, try Roslyn if you haven't spent too much energy on Harmony. Roslyn is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed out in comments, [`Roslyn DataFlowAnalysis`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.dataflowanalysis?view=roslyn-dotnet) is probably the best tool for the job:

```cs
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
    @"public class foo
    {
        private int field;
        public void method()
        {
             field = 0;
        }
    }");
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("test").AddSyntaxTrees(tree).AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var methodDeclaration = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();

var dataFlow = model.AnalyzeDataFlow(methodDeclaration.Body);
foreach (var symbol in dataFlow.DataFlowsIn)
{
    Console.WriteLine(symbol.Name, symbol.Kind);
}
```

analysis for your particular example yields reference to class `foo` through implicit 
 `this`, but not the `field` itself (which is technically correct but not very helpful). Assuming your actual code will likely have a bit more dependencies in it - you may see better results.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the list of [opcodes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions) in IL you find that you want to search for `OpCodes.Ldfld` and `OpCodes.Ldflda`. Harmony’s `CodeInstruction` has two fields to use: compare `code` to either opcode and use `operand` and cast it to a `FieldInfo` to learn about what field is read. Use `OpCodes.Stfld(a)` for write access to fields.